# Usage of a verb "encode": is it possible to use it like "something encodes some information"?

Tags: verbs, word-usage

In a scientific context, I want to use the word "encode" in such a way as

- "The object *A* encodes the object *B*.", or
- "The object *A* encoding the object *B* is defined by ...".

By this sentence, I am trying to say that the information of *B* is embedded in *A*.
Is it possible to use "encode" in this way?
I think that "*B* is encoded in *A*." is OK but I am not sure if this usage is OK, too.

Thanks in advance.

---Edited---

In my case, *A* is a gate operation or a logical circuit in a computer (in fact, a quantum computer), and *B* is a mathematical function.

Comment: Normally, _encode_ is a causative verb, so you'd say _the algorithm encodes the text_. But you can also use it in discussing substitution codes, like _ROT13 uses the ASCII character 13 places away from a given ASCII alphabetic character to encode that character._

Comment: Have you tried searcing the Web, Google Books, etc.? It's often not hard to find examples of how words are used.

Comment: An object does not encode, unless it is a machine, or an abstract function. Did you mean "contains"?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's wrong with "B is encoded in A" or "A is an encoding of B"?

Comment: Object A is a kind of an abstract function (an operation), but "contain" would work for me. Thank you.
I wanted to use this kind of expression because I need to write a sentence whose subject is A in a compact form, like "A containing the information of B is defined by ..., and implemented by ...".

Comment: In the case of a gate and a function, I'd probably say that the gate *implements* the function. The terminology that one entity encodes another is quite common in mathematics and computer science, but  it doesn't seem right in your particular gate-function context.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will consider using "implement", too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with answering your question correctly is that you haven't defined what "A" and "B" are in your examples.

> By this sentence, I am trying to say that the information of B is embedded in A.

Sheet music *encodes* some musical events, and a string of bytes (together with a certain character table, e.g. ASCII) *encodes* some text, but if you enclose a letter in a biography, this biography doesn't "encode" the letter.

One of the prerequisites of *encoding* is that a certain translation process takes place: in case of text encoding, this could be the ASCII table, which translates (8-bit) numbers to characters and vice versa. In case of a ROT13, cipher "A" encodes "N", "B" encodes "O", and so on.

The relationship between *encoded* data and *encoding* data doesn't need to be 1:1 either. Compression algorithms (both lossless and lossy, like TIFF, ones) are also a form of encoding.

---- EDIT: -----

Given the further context you provided in your edit: yes, you could use "encode" in this case, because the mentioned "translation" - that is, doing something by means of doing something else - is in fact taking place: you operate a gate and, by doing that, calculate a mathematical function.

Comment: Its certainly context related.  For instance, "the JPEG file format encodes images" vs "this JPEG contains encoded image data."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry that my question was too vague.
In my case, "A" is a gate operation (or a logic circuit) in a computer (in fact, a quantum computer), and "B" is a mathematical function.

Comment: Thank you, bakunin, for the additional answer. It helped me a lot!